# How do you use custom font families with Xamarin CSS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Xamarin CSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/) lets you specify a `font-family` using a syntax similar to CSS. I need to set a **custom** font. Usually that looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="RockwellFontLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="RockwellStd.otf#RockwellStd.otf" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="RockwellStd" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Setter>
</Style>

...

<Label Style="{StaticResource RockwellFontLabel}" Text="I AM TEXT"/>
```

Which, while verbose, does work. But Xamarin CSS promises so much more. I can do things like set the font family for a whole section with just one "CSS" rule, right? RIGHT?!

```
#myElement * {
    font-family: 'RockwellStd';
    color: hotpink;
}
```

But that only sets the color. It doesn't set my custom font family at all. Obviously on Android the font is located under `/Assets/RockwellStd.otf` with a Build Action set to `AndroidAsset` and `/Resources/Fonts/RockwellStd.otf` with a build action of `BundleResource`.

Is it possible to use a custom font with Xamarin CSS? If so, how?

Comment: If you are using .otf you need set to label text "\uyourIconCode" (for example: "\uf0c5") .Here is a similar issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138430/how-to-add-custom-fonts-on-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the question here about CSS is very valid, it would be one of the big advantages of using Styling in Xamarin Forms > applying to all children in a set.

But the current ( as of writing ) state of CSS inside Xamarin Forms is still what limited. In that sense that targeting a possible `StaticResource` for custom font definition per plaform inside CSS styling is still not possible.
Reference of said question to David Ortinau the Xamarin Forms PM at the time ( https://twitter.com/Depechie/status/1001944818543718400 ).

So for now we can only solve this with some xaml styling, I suggest you do keep your original `StaticResource` style definition for the custom font per platform. But instead of applying it inside the general `App.xaml`, try only setting it inside the `ResourceDictionary` property of the View or UI element where you want it only to occur.

If you try to use `Implicit Styling` inside that `ResourceDictionary`, you won't need to add the `Style="{StaticResource RockwellFontLabel}"` tag to each Label element.

Comment: This works! It's not CSS but it accomplished what I was going for anyhow. That is, I can declare a style once for all child elements of an element. Sorry that this is inlined but here is a working example:

Comment: `<StackLayout x:Name="myScopedElement"> <StackLayout.Resources> <ResourceDictionary> <Style TargetType="Label"> <Setter Property="FontFamily"> <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"> <On Platform="Android" Value="RockwellStd.otf#RockwellStd.otf" /> <On Platform="iOS" Value="RockwellStd" /> </OnPlatform> </Setter> </Style> </ResourceDictionary> </StackLayout.Resources> <StackLayout x:Name="myElement"> <!-- my body content. all the labels in here will get RockwellStd --> </StackLayout> </StackLayout>`